# Why the Vagrant do not share folders on windows 8 64bits e 32bits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using:

```
Windows 8 64-bit
vagrant 1.7.2
Virtual Box 4.3.28
GitBash 1.9.4 for SSH connection
Box Ubuntu 14:04:02 Trusty32 and
Box Ubuntu 14:04:02 Trusty64
```

I am using everioment development ruby on rails on ubuntu/trusty32 and trusty/64 on vagrant to windows64.
Everything is worked well, but i don`t can share the folders on windows between vagrant.

This is my Vagrant File:

```
   # -*- mode: ruby -*-
   # vi: set ft=ruby :

   # All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure 
   # configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
   # backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what 
   # you're doing.
   Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
   # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
   # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
   # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

   # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
   # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
   config.vm.box = "trusty64"

   # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
   # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
   # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
   # config.vm.box_check_update = false

   # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
   # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
   # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
   # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

   # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
   # using a specific IP.
   # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

   # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
   # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
   # your network.
   # config.vm.network "public_network"

   # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
   # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
   # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
   # argument is a set of non-required options.
   # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

   # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
   # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
   # Example for VirtualBox:
   #
   # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
   #   vb.gui = true
   #
   #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
   #   vb.memory = "1024"
   # end
   #
   # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
   # information on available options.

   # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
   # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
   # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
   # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
   #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
   # end

   # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
   # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
   # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
   # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   #   sudo apt-get update
   #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
   # SHELL
end
```

Trusty64 on windows does not connect.
Trusty32 on Windows ok, but does not share.

Comment: Can you share your vagrantfile please? Window32 not support nfs (little feedback)

Comment: @GianArb i changed to Windows64, but the connection continuing does not sharing the folders. i put the vagrant file.

Comment: Window not support nfs.. :) config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data" use this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using another box I found in vagrantcloud.
First set up in Mac after everything working, I fathered a litter box (package) and went pro Windows8, did the normal procedure and it worked!

I recomento that use 64bit, Window32 not support nfs, and enable virtualization in bios.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem on a similar configuration and this fixed it:

1. vagrant ssh
2. sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
3. exit
4. vagrant reload